# How do I get Javascript to work with ASP treeview?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, treeview

I set up an interactive video playlist in HTML and Javascript that plays videos in an HTML5 video player window on the same page as the playlist. It works fine. Now I have been told that the playlist has to be set up in an ASP treeview, but I can't get the Javascript work with the ASP code. How can I change the code to get it to work? Code is below:

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#TreeView1 TreeNode").on("click", function () {
        $("#videoarea").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("NavigateUrl"),
            "poster": "",
            "autoplay": "autoplay"
        })
    })
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $("#TreeView1 TreeNode").eq(0).attr(NavigateUrl"),
        "poster": $("#TreeView1 TreeNode").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    })
})
```

ASPX::

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ViewVideos.aspx.cs" Inherits="VideoWebApp.ViewVideos" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="videoapp.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="VideoApp.js"></script> 

    <title>Video Library</title>

</head>

<body>

 <%--   <div class="wrap">--%>

        <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div class="top">
        <img src="art/tpmtrans.png" alt="TPM" class="logo"/>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
        <h3>Instructional Videos</h3>
        <br/>

        <asp:TreeView clientidmode="Static" ID="TreeView1" runat="server">

    <Nodes> 
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Movies">
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Movie 1" NavigateUrl="~/videos/Movie1.webm" Target="_blank"/>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Movie 2" NavigateUrl="~/videos/Movie2.webm" Target="_blank"/>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Movie 3" NavigateUrl="~/Movie3.aspx" Target="_blank"/>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Movie 4" NavigateUrl="~/Movie4.aspx" Target="_blank"/>
        </asp:TreeNode>
    </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>

    </div>

    <div class="main">
            <div>
                <p>

                    <video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="ART/Welcome-Poster.png " src=""></video>


                </p>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well for one, your script uses the ID playlist and your treeview control does not. Also, ASP.NET will change your ID when it is rendered and you need to account for that in your client script.

Comment: I edited the code above to what I now have. The treeview has the ClientID set to Static, and I reworked the Javascript. The video still opens up a new window instead of playing in the HTML5 video player window on the same page as the playlist.